# Why does binding not work for user controls in .net maui?

Tags: c#, maui

I have a custom AvtorizeEntry control

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SWMClient.Infrastructure.Controls.AvtorizeEntry"
             x:Name="AvtorizeEntryControl"
             BindingContext="{x:Reference AvtorizeEntryControl}">

    <Border
                WidthRequest="320"
                Opacity="0.7"
                StrokeThickness="1"
                Stroke="black"
                HorizontalOptions="Center">

        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Image Margin="5" Source="{Binding ImageEntry}" WidthRequest="35"/>
            <Entry TextColor="Black" WidthRequest="250" Text="{Binding EntryText }"/>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Border>
    
</ContentView>
```

And its properties

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty EntryTextProperty =
                     BindableProperty.Create("EntryText", typeof(string), typeof(AvtorizeEntry));
public string EntryText
{
    get => (string)GetValue(EntryTextProperty);
    set => SetValue(EntryTextProperty, value);
}

public static readonly BindableProperty ImageEntryProperty =
                     BindableProperty.Create("ImageEntry", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(AvtorizeEntry));
public ImageSource ImageEntry
{
    get => (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageEntryProperty);
    set => SetValue(ImageEntryProperty, value);
}
```

but when trying to bind it to the page ViewModel

```
            <controls:AvtorizeEntry EntryText="{Binding Login }" ImageEntry="profel.png"/>
```

ViewModel
partial class RegistrationViewModel : ObservableObject
{
#region Propertys

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    
    private string pasword = "pasword";

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string login = "login";

    #endregion
```

Nothing happens. The binding just doesn't work. Why is the binding not working?

Comment: You are not setting the BindingContext

Comment: Sorry I didn't show it, I have BindingContext installed      <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:RegistrationViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

Comment: Your ContentView needs a BindingContext

Comment: <ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SWMClient.Infrastructure.Controls.AvtorizeEntry"
             x:Name="AvtorizeEntryControl"
             BindingContext="{x:Reference AvtorizeEntryControl}">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off. Controls need to be standalone. So never have a binding context in them. Your control should look like this:

```
<ContentView
    x:Class="MauiTest.Controls.AvtorizeEntry"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Border
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Opacity="0.7"
            Stroke="black"
            StrokeThickness="1"
            WidthRequest="320">

            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                <Image
                    x:Name="Image1"
                    Margin="5"
                    WidthRequest="35" />
                <Entry
                    x:Name="Entry1"
                    TextChanged="Entry1_TextChanged"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    WidthRequest="250" />
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </Border>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Secondly you need to take care of the changes you do for the properties. So your Control code behind is this:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class AvtorizeEntry : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty EntryTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(EntryText),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(AvtorizeEntry),
                null,
                BindingMode.TwoWay,
                propertyChanged: OnEntryTextPropertyChanged, propertyChanging: OnEntryTextPropertyChanging);

    private static void OnEntryTextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (AvtorizeEntry)bindable;
        control.Entry1.Text = (string)newValue; 
    }

    private void Entry1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var entry = (Entry)sender;
        EntryText = entry.Text;

    }

    public string EntryText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(EntryTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(EntryTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageEntryProperty =
                         BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ImageEntry), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(AvtorizeEntry), null, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnImageEntryPropertyChanged);

    private static void OnImageEntryPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (AvtorizeEntry)bindable;
        control.Image1.Source = (ImageSource)newValue;
    }


    public ImageSource ImageEntry
    {
        get => (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageEntryProperty);
        set => SetValue(ImageEntryProperty, value);
    }
    public AvtorizeEntry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

}

And as always you need to bind your View to your ViewModel either in your xaml or in your code behind. This is the xaml:

```
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MauiTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MauiTest.Controls"
    xmlns:drawables="clr-namespace:MauiTest.Drawables"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiTest.Drawables"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiTest.ViewModels"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MauiTest.Views"
    Title="Test"
    Background="White">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:TestViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>


    <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">

        <controls:AvtorizeEntry EntryText="{Binding Login}" ImageEntry="dotnet_bot.svg" />

    </VerticalStackLayout>


</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I wouldn't say "never" about the binding context of controls, but I agree that in most cases, it's not required to set it explicitly as it is usually inherited or passed down by the parent, which usually is a Page (but sometimes also another View).

Comment: The binding has started working, but it is not updated if you change the values in the entry

Comment: Are you using code like this: "Login =" with a capital L? If you use lower case it will not work.

Comment: Yes, I write with a capital

Comment: From the ViewModel? If you set an Breakpoint does it stop where you update the Property?

Comment: <controls:AvtorizeEntry EntryText="{Binding Login}" ImageEntry="profel.png"/>
            <controls:AvtorizeEntry EntryText="{Binding Pasword }" ImageEntry="pasword.png"/>

Comment: Dictionary<string, string> ReqwestData = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    ["login"] = Login,
                    ["password"] = Pasword,
                };

Comment: #region Propertys

        [ObservableProperty]
        private string pasword = "frostwert123";

        [ObservableProperty]
        private string login = "wert123";

        #endregion

Comment: This seem to be another thing. you are trying to update a Dictionary with a property before it has gotten any value. Am I missing something?

Comment: [RelayCommand]
        private async Task LogIn()
        {
            var response = ApiClient.LogIn(Login, Password);

            if (await response != null)
            {
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//MainPage");
            }
            
        }

Comment: I first enter my login and password and at the click of a button I have to send them to ApiClient

Comment: I have updated control to handle text updates. Now you will get the text from the Entry.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the `BindingContext` of the control like that, you can simply use the value provided as the `x:Name` of the control and use it directly in the binding expression as a `Source`, e.g.: `Source="{Binding ImageEntry, Source={x:Reference AvtorizeEntryControl}}"`

Change your XAML to look like this:

```xml
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SWMClient.Infrastructure.Controls.AvtorizeEntry"
             x:Name="AvtorizeEntryControl">

    <Border
        WidthRequest="320"
        Opacity="0.7"
        StrokeThickness="1"
        Stroke="black"
        HorizontalOptions="Center">

        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Image Margin="5" Source="{Binding ImageEntry, Source={x:Reference AvtorizeEntryControl}}" WidthRequest="35"/>
            <Entry TextColor="Black" WidthRequest="250" Text="{Binding EntryText, Source={x:Reference AvtorizeEntryControl}}"/>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Border>
    
</ContentView>
```

Then you can use the control in your Page like follows:

```xml
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"    
    xmlns:vm="YourProject.AnotherNamespace"
    x:Class="YourProject.SomeNamespace.SomePage"
    x:DataType="vm:SomeViewModel">

    <Grid>
        <controls:AvtorizeEntry
            EntryText="{Binding Login}"
            ImageEntry="profel.png"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Make sure to set the `BindingContext` of the Page to the ViewModel where you have defined your properties *(technically, you can also set the `BindingContext` from within the XAML, but that's less common for a couple of reasons such as dependency injection)*:

```cs
namespace YourProject.SomeNamespace;

public partial class SomePage : ContentPage
{
    public SomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new SomeViewModel();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```cs
//using ...

namespace YourProject.AnotherNamespace;

public partial class SomeViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string login = "login";
}
```